# "JOIN expression not supported" in Access, how to edit query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in an Access 2010 database that looks roughly like this:

```
select * from (table1 inner join table2 on table1.city = table2.code)
   inner join table3 on table3.col1 = table2.col1 and table3.col2 = table2.col2;
```

The query is used in a report, which works fine (I can run the report and get the data). However, when I try to open the query (in either datasheet or design view), I get **JOIN expression not supported**.

I know what that means—nested JOINs as well as long ON conditions need to be placed in parentheses. The following would work:

```
select * from (table1 inner join table2 on table1.city = table2.code)
   inner join table3 on (table3.col1 = table2.col1 and table3.col2 = table2.col2);
```

Now here's the catch: When I save the query and open it later, **Access removes the parentheses again.** As a result, I get the same error again. The Access GUI doesn't provide a way to open the query in SQL view directly, and opening it in Design or Datasheet view gives the error before I have a chance to fix the SQL code. (In datasheet view, the data displays, with the error dialog appearing on top of it, and closes as soon as I click OK.)

**How can I get at the SQL code of my query in this situation?**

Comment: Try saving your subqueries as stand-alone separate queries and use those in your "higher level" query.

Comment: My query designer produces this for a join on 2 columns, try this: `inner join table3 on (table3.col1 = table2.col1) and (table3.col2 = table2.col2)` (parentheses around each join column set). But parentheses around the whole ON clause aren't needed AFAIK. -- Is there a reason to not use the query designer?

Comment: All well and fair, but I can't change the query because of the error—my question was about a workaround to **get at the SQL code**. I finally found a solution (see below). Fixing the SQL code itself turned out to be pretty easy—turns out my second JOIN clause ended in `ON table3.col1 = table2.col1 AND table3.col2 = 'value'`, which could easily be rewritten as `ON table3.col1 = table2.col1 WHERE table3.col2 = 'value'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VBA macro to extract the SQL code of a query is shown [here](http://plosquare.blogspot.de/2009/08/solution-for-join-expression-not.html).

First, create a VBA module. In the module, create the following sub:

```
Public Sub printBrokenQuery()
    Debug.Print CurrentDb().QueryDefs("BrokenQuery").SQL
End Sub
```

Hit Ctrl+G to bring up the Immediate window (which shows debug output). Then run tht sub above by placing the cursor in the source code and hitting F5.

Now create another sub:

```
Public Sub setBrokenQuery()
    CurrentDb().QueryDefs("Broken").SQL = _
    "(your query here)"
End Sub
```

Take the source code of your query and figure out how to fix it (there are a few answers on that). Eventually, paste the SQL code into your new sub where it says `(your query here)`. Place the cursor in that sub and run it. Voilà—problem solved. The VBA module can be deleted once you've fixed the error.